# Show Dialog Box or proceed to Camera Screen

Tags: dart, flutter

Hi all I have this below code I want to show a dialog if it return an error but proceed to the camera screen if no error is returned, I want it to show the error the was return in the dialog. The function below returns results based on which we can either proceed to the camera screen or return error messages. Please help me to figure this issue out Thank you!

```
  import 'dart:async';

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() {
    return new HomePageState();
  }
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String result = "Hey there !";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    //check to see if barcode is scanned
    try {

      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Camera permission was denied";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("QR Scanner"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          result,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        label: Text("Scan"),
        onPressed: _scanQR,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: On click of scan button, you are opening Barcode scanner (camera), are you facing problem in that. Please provide some information

Comment: From your question no I am not facing any problem when you read the code carefully you will see that it has a try method with different conditions which returns different results(errors) if there is no the camera opens, but want I want to do is to use a dialog box to sure the errors otherwise if there is no error it should proceed to  opening the camera and return the results from the camera